# How to change the Linux Mint Nadia splash screen?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, bootsplash

I was wondering if it is possible for me to change the splash screen when Linux Mint is loading? I am talking about the logo of mint which appears when you start the computer. If so what kind of file format is it? And is it difficult to do?

Answer (score 1):

I found this tutorial for Katya (Linux Mint 11) that might be helpful, titled: [How to Install a Splash Screen on Linux Mint](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/install-splash-screen-linux-mint-39045.html).

This approach makes use of [Startup Manager](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/startupmanager).

#### General steps

1. Install Startup Manager
2. Launch Startup Manager
3. Click on the "Boot options" tab and place a check-mark in front of the "Show boot splash" option.
4. Click on the "Appearance" tab and click on the "Manage usplash themes" button. Use the resulting file browser to select the splash screen you want to use and click "OK."
5. Click "Close" to save the changes and close the Startup Manager window.
6. Reboot Linux Mint to see the new splash screen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the Startup Manager is no longer available for download nor is it supported. Is there any other easy method of changing the splash screen?

Comment: I'll have to research some more. If I find anything I'll report back.

Comment: @Jakub you want to either change the Plymouth theme or, according to slm's answer, the usplash theme. I'd just try Googling for that; there's probably loads of tools for it. maybe try `apt-cache search plymouth-theme`, IIRC?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [release notes of Maya (Linux Mint 13)](http://linuxmint.com/rel_maya.php) (should be applicable to Nadia as well), you can change a splash screen by changing the plymouth theme by running

`sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`

in your terminal.

For more on this, check the first point on [this link](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1149).